# How to implement caching in Strapi or implementing indexing on strapi

Tags: performance, caching, indexing, strapi

Where do I add the cache control headers in the strapi dashboard?

Here is the link to my strapi forum [question](https://forum.strapi.io/t/how-to-implement-caching-on-strapi-api-layer/33787)

Unable to find that in the documentation. Please suggest a way to cache the strapi Rest API’s.

I was also looking a way to index the strapi database but I unable to find the right documentation to implement that.

As the strapi dataset has increased and I want to improve my rest api response time.

Comment: https://docs.strapi.io/cloud/getting-started/caching 
I am referring to this one.

Comment: https://forum.strapi.io/t/how-to-implement-caching-on-strapi-api-layer/33787

So sorry

Comment: I have tried this as well https://strapi.io/blog/caching-in-strapi-with-rest-cache-plugin but it did not work for me.